# How can I type certain days (such as Monday, Wednesday) in an easy way for the next 5 months without typing them one by one?

Tags: batch, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice

I am trying to input in a libreoffice calc file only Mondays and Wednesdays for the next 5 months, but I dont wanna do it typing the dates one by one. So..I thought I would type 4 dates like this:

```
17. Mar. 2014   Monday  
19. Mar. 2014   Wednesday  
24. Mar. 2014   Monday  
26. Mar. 2014   Wednesday
```

Then I thought highlighting these dates and dragging them would give me all the Mondays and Wednesdays up to the a point where I drag it....but this is what I get:

```
17. Mar. 2014   Monday
19. Mar. 2014   Wednesday
24. Mar. 2014   Monday
26. Mar. 2014   Wednesday
18. Mar. 2014   Thursday
20. Mar. 2014   Friday
25. Mar. 2014   Saturday
27. Mar. 2014   Sunday
```

Is there a way for me to put only Mondays and Wednesdays in a fairly simple way instead of typing them one by one?

Comment: You're right, the question isn't understandable. You want to copy Monday's and Wednesdays'.... what? Also, please take the time to format the question correctly -1

Comment: Please give more details!

Comment: There. Just edited it. I hopè it helps.
I simply wanna find an easy, automated way to write Mondays and Wednesdays into an libreoffice calc file instead of typing them in one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Write the first 2 days that you want, say `17 Mar 2014` and `19 Mar 2014` and the associated day-of-week in the cells beside them.

Cell `A3` is `=A1+7`

Cell `A4` is `=A2+7`

Drag and repeat.